# How can I divide column values by group in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to change the following dataframe form to join with other df.

```
+--+----+---+
|id|type|num|
+--+----+---+
| 1|   A|  1|
| 1|   B|  3|
| 2|   A|  2|
| 3|   B|  4|
| 4|   B|  2|
+--+----+---+
```

to

```
+--+-----+-----+
|id|num_A|num_B|
+--+-----+-----+
| 1|    1|    3|
| 2|    2|     |
| 3|     |    4|
| 4|     |    2|
+--+-----+-----+
```

The only way I know is using `left outer join`, `right outer join` and `union`, but it's a little bit complex... Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just requires conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
    max(case when type='A' then num end) num_A,
    max(case when type='B' then num end) num_B
from mysterytablename
group by id
```

(That will return null for missing values; if you want blank instead, add `coalesce( max(...), '')`